# Map columns in pandas using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new column, which will contain letters {a,b,c,d} based on rules:

```
{'a' if (df['q1']==0 & df['q2']==0), 
 'b' if (df['q1']==0 & df['q2']==1),
 'c' if (df['q1']==1 & df['q2']==0),
 'd' if (df['q1']==1 & df['q2']==1)}
```

so, the new third column should contain a letter which corresponds to a particular combination of {0,1} in two columns.

```
         q1      q2
0         0       1
1         0       1
2         0       1
3         0       1
4         0       1
5         0       1
6         0       1
7         0       1
8         0       1
9         0       1
10        1       1
11        1       1
12        0       1
13        0       1
14        1       0
15        0       0
16        0       0
17        0       0
18        0       0
19        0       0
20        0       0
21        0       0
```

I thought about converting numbers in each row from binary to decimal format and then apply dictionary rules.

Comment: Use apply function on the dataframe. Pass each row to a function where you check for the condition and return the row for the new column

Comment: @bigbounty, sounds good, however I'm wondering if it possible 'less straightforward' way, more pythonian.

Comment: You can use lambda functions in the apply function on the dataframe itself

Comment: `df['val'] = (ord('a') + 2 * df['q1'] + df['q2']).apply(chr)` - I'm already out ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) by `Series` with `MultiIndex`:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1],[0,1]], names=('q1','q2'))
s = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'], index=idx, name='val')
print (s)
q1  q2
0   0     a
    1     b
1   0     c
    1     d
Name: val, dtype: object

df = df.join(s, on=['q1','q2'])
print (df)
    q1  q2 val
0    0   1   b
1    0   1   b
2    0   1   b
3    0   1   b
4    0   1   b
5    0   1   b
6    0   1   b
7    0   1   b
8    0   1   b
9    0   1   b
10   1   1   d
11   1   1   d
12   0   1   b
13   0   1   b
14   1   0   c
15   0   0   a
16   0   0   a
17   0   0   a
18   0   0   a
19   0   0   a
20   0   0   a
21   0   0   a
```

Comment: Brilliant, I have read a lot of your answers and your answers are good @jezrael

Comment: sometimes yes, sometimes not. But sometimes get nice idea. thanks.

Comment: @jezrael, you should publish a book on pandas. Just copy paste all your solutions  :)

Comment: @ArnoldKlein - I think it is problem, because my horrible English ;)

Comment: @jezrael ,please name it "Short Hand Pandas" if possible

Comment: @ArnoldKlein While this solution is amazing, you should take a look at mine, just as a reference for other possible solutions. /plug

Comment: @COLDSPEED, sure, thanks!! I'm learning 'neat' pandas, so any solutions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Another method with `df.map` and `df.transform`:

```
In [90]: mapping = {(0, 0) :'a', (0, 1) : 'b', (1, 0): 'c', (1, 1): 'd'}

In [91]: df['val'] = df.transform(lambda x: (x['q1'], x['q2']), axis=1).map(mapping); df
Out[91]: 
    q1  q2 val
0    0   1   b
1    0   1   b
2    0   1   b
3    0   1   b
4    0   1   b
5    0   1   b
6    0   1   b
7    0   1   b
8    0   1   b
9    0   1   b
10   1   1   d
11   1   1   d
12   0   1   b
13   0   1   b
14   1   0   c
15   0   0   a
16   0   0   a
17   0   0   a
18   0   0   a
19   0   0   a
20   0   0   a
21   0   0   a
```

You can also use `zip` to generate columns, apply `pd.Series` and then do the mapping:

```
In [119]: df['val'] = pd.Series(list(zip(df.q1, df.q2))).map(mapping); df
Out[119]: 
    q1  q2 val
0    0   1   b
1    0   1   b
2    0   1   b
3    0   1   b
4    0   1   b
5    0   1   b
6    0   1   b
7    0   1   b
8    0   1   b
9    0   1   b
10   1   1   d
11   1   1   d
12   0   1   b
13   0   1   b
14   1   0   c
15   0   0   a
16   0   0   a
17   0   0   a
18   0   0   a
19   0   0   a
20   0   0   a
21   0   0   a
```

---

## Performance

jezrael's solution:

```
In [552]: %%timeit
     ...: idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1],[0,1]], names=('q1','q2'))
     ...: s = pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'], index=idx, name='val')
     ...: df.join(s, on=['q1','q2'])
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.84 ms per loop
```

Proposed in this post:

```
In [553]: %%timeit
     ...: mapping = {(0, 0) :'a', (0, 1) : 'b', (1, 0): 'c', (1, 1): 'd'}
     ...: df.transform(lambda x: (x['q1'], x['q2']), axis=1).map(mapping)
     ...:  
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED, actually, your solution is more intuitive and this is how I thought to solve it (however, lacking some knowledge about zipping).

Comment: @ArnoldKlein You should do a timing comparison of jezrael's method and mine, and then reconsider which method you want to use :)

Comment: @ArnoldKlein Actually, I did it for you.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, highly appreciated! Will do benchmark. Thanks again.